# Relevel every factor at once in dplyr chain

Tags: r, dplyr

I want all factors that have the underscore "_importance" to be releveled in the following order: "Don't care at all"  , "Care a little",  "Care somewhat", "Care somewhat strongly", "Care Strongly"

I'm currently doing the following to convert from character to factor classes, but cannot figure out how to relevel within a pipe:

```
test <- test %>%
  select(contains("_importance")) %>%
  mutate_if(is.character, as.factor)
```

Comment: are you creating a subset of columns or do you want to update the original dataset?

Comment: I want to update the original dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fct_relevel` from `forcats`.

```
library(forcats)
library(dplyr)

neworder <- c("Don't care at all" , "Care a little", "Care somewhat", "Care somewhat strongly", "Care Strongly")

test  %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(contains("_importance")), ~fct_relevel(.x, neworder))
```

Note that `fct_relevel` can also apply functions on the current factor levels, so if, for example, you just wanted to reverse the current levels you could do `fct_relevel(f, rev)`

Comment: Thanks so much! What is the importance of the ~ and the dot before x?

Comment: I'm also getting the following error: `Unknown levels in `f`: Care StronglyUnknown levels in `f`: Care somewhat strongly, Care StronglyUnknown levels in `f`: Care a little, Care somewhat strongly, Care StronglyUnknown levels in `f`: Care somewhat, Care somewhat strongly` because not every variable with "_importance" contains all the levels.  Is there a way to correct this?

Comment: Relevelling applies to existing factor levels so you will run into problems if you include levels that don't already exist in the data.  If you want to overwrite existing factor labels you could use `fct_relabel` which will replace, in order, old labels with new labels but these must be of equal length.  The `~` is a `purrr`-style formula shortcut that saves writing an anonymous function with the `.x` being the pre-defined parameter for the function.